# Finding the cause of array.push TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

I feel I'm missing something small but just can't find it. Any Ideas on why this code is giving me a Javascript TypeError and points at the "SQLValuseBoltUp?

```
 //Build SQL VALUES list
for(var counterBoltUp1 = 0; counterBoltUp1 < data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table.length; counterBoltUp1++){
  SQLValuesBoltUp.push("('" + data.Entry.SubmissionId + "'");
  for(var counterBoltUp2 = 0; counterBoltUp2 < data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table[counterBoltUp1].Answers.length; counterBoltUp2++){
    SQLValuesBoltUp.push("'" + data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table[counterBoltUp1].Answers[counterBoltUp2].Value + (counterBoltUp2 < data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table[counterBoltUp1].Answers.length - 1 ? "'" : "')" ) );
  }
}
```

EDIT:  to clearify Yes the variable SQLValuesBoltup is initialized prior here:

```
var SQLValuesBoltUp = [];
var PageIndexBoltUp = 2;
```

As well so is data here:

`var data = JSON.parse(request.body);`

When doing the SQLValuesBoltUp.push with the following manual written out code, it works:

```
SQLValuesBoltUp.push("('" + data.Entry.SubmissionId + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[0].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[1].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[2].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[3].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[4].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[5].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[6].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[7].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[8].Value + "')");
```

As for the Error, That is all the details I'm able to get out of the interface I'm using and have yet to find a way to find more details to the error to share.

For further clarification. Below is the code in its entirety:

```
//Static variables

var SQLFieldNamesBoltUp = "";
var SQLValuesBoltUp = [];
var PageIndexBoltUp = 2;
googleDBBoltUp.request = new AP.MySQL.Request();


//Automaticaly builds SQLFieldNames list by querying tblSubsBoltUp
for (var counterBoltUp = 1; counterBoltUp < googleDB1.response.data.length; counterBoltUp++){
  if(counterBoltUp != googleDB1.response.data.length - 1){
    SQLFieldNamesBoltUp = SQLFieldNamesBoltUp + googleDB1.response.data[counterBoltUp].COLUMN_NAME + ", "; 
  }else{
    SQLFieldNamesBoltUp = SQLFieldNamesBoltUp + googleDB1.response.data[counterBoltUp].COLUMN_NAME;
  }
}


//Build SQL VALUES list
for(var counterBoltUp1 = 0; counterBoltUp1 < data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table.length; counterBoltUp1++){
  SQLValuesBoltUp.push("('" + data.Entry.SubmissionId + "'");
  for(var counterBoltUp2 = 0; counterBoltUp2 < data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table[counterBoltUp1].Answers.length; counterBoltUp2++){
    SQLValuesBoltUp.push("'" + data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table[counterBoltUp1].Answers[counterBoltUp2].Value + (counterBoltUp2 < data.Entry.Page[PageIndexBoltUp].Table[counterBoltUp1].Answers.length - 1 ? "'" : "')" ) );
  }
}

/*
  SQLValuesBoltUp.push("('" + data.Entry.SubmissionId + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[0].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[1].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[2].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[3].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[4].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[5].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[6].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[7].Value + "'",
  "'" + data.Entry.Page[2].Table[0].Answers[8].Value + "')");
*/
//}
```

Comment: Did you remember to initialize the variable before you started pushing into it? `var SQLValuesBoltUp = [];`

Comment: Yes, variable is initialized prior with:  `var SQLValuesBoltUp = [];` `code`

Comment: I'm not sure what I changed.. but just started looking trough it from ground zero and a fresh JSON data, and it is working as needed now...  I'm assuming I had made a change in my JSON data that was creating an undefined that the push would not handle...    Will continue to test it, but thanks for the help